# Android Studio Kotlin webview app crashing when selecting an image after selecting the option from a sheet dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, webview

I have a bottom sheet dialog that opens up when I select the file input of a webview.
From this dialog I have 2 options that I can select from.

Choosing from device files or use the camera to take a photo of a document.
(I am still building on the camera functionality)

```
                webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {


                    //THIS HANDLES THE CLICK FOR THE FILE INPUT BUTTON
                    override fun onShowFileChooser(mWebView: WebView, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams): Boolean {
                        bottomSheetDialog.show()
                        var theReturn = false

                        view.from_files.setOnClickListener{
                            // HANDLE THE FILE SELECT
                            // ###############################################################
                            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                                uploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(null)
                                uploadMessage = null
                            }
                            uploadMessage = filePathCallback
                            var intent: Intent? = null
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent()
                                theReturn = true
                            }
                            try {
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
                            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                                uploadMessage = null
                                theReturn = false
                            }
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                        // ===
                        view.from_camera.setOnClickListener{
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "In the camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            theReturn = false
                        }

                        return theReturn
                    }
                }
```

The onShowFileChooser functions require a true or false to return. The function seems to work when clicking the File input element and selecting the camera option, this only displays a Toast at this point.

When I do click the files function I can navigate and select a file, after that the app crashes.
It seems like the true value is not passed from this section.

I am doing something wrong here, just can't figure out what it could be.

Thank you in advance for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your variable needs to be declared as a global variable. If I understand your code, the theReturn value will be initiated as false every time the webview is recreated.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, I am getting the same crash with the variable declared as global